# How to sort Visual Studio 2012 CSS Outline class names?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to sort alphabetically the class names in Visual Studio's CSS Outline window?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code 1.27.2, hover on the outline panel, click on the three dots, you've the sort option

[image]